# Does it matter which microphone is used for sound recognition?

Tags: speech-recognition, audio-recording, google-search, google-translate, sound-recognition

If yes, then how does audio recognition apps work in different devices ?

For example, Google translate works in iphone-6, samsung-s6, htc-m9 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does matter which microphone is used, modern speech recognition systems are very specific about microphones and there are really bad microphones sometimes, in particular cheap desktop microphones. It also matters what audio card do you use, many cheap cards record with a lot of noises, in particular on desktops and that reduces recognition rate sufficiently.

Far-talking microphones record room echo which is very harmful for recognition. Lapel microphone which are close to mouth are way better.

Recent improvements in speech recognition accuracy reduced this problem but it is still important.

For that reason Nuance in particular recommends to use external USB microphones instead of embedded ones.

Most high-end smart phones have quite good microphones for that reason you do not need to worry about them. This is because they have no electrical noise being powered on direct current. They also designed for good speech quality recordings.

Audio quality is still a problem for cheap phones and cheap desktop microphones.

Comment: As I know, modern sound recognition system, e.g. deep learning, usually requires a vast amount of data to train a model. How can developers get it if they develop on desktops? Recording by themselves seems to be inefficient.

Comment: This is why Google promotes Deep Learning as a magic technology, it basically locks all research to a large scale companies who can afford a lot of computing power and data collection resources. There are two main directions people could use: develop a distributed peer-to-peer optimization to collect resources all over the world (BOINC style) or develop more efficient algorithms for training.

Comment: Hi! I was experimenting to train models with sounds recording from different microphones. First, I downloaded a dataset from a website, and it contains many kinds of sound. Second, I recorded some sounds by my own microphone on the desktop. This two datasets are the same sampling rate and both mono.

Comment: I tried to train a model which could recognize two sounds, one is class-A from "download dataset" and another is class-Z from "record dataset". Then, I used class-B from "download dataset" to test, and the result is usually class-A. While using class-Y from "record dataset" to test, and the result is usually class-Z.

Comment: That is: A, B, Y, Z are different sounds. A, B are from a download dataset. Y, Z are recorded by myself. Model is trained to recognize A and Z. The result is that B is classified to A and Y is classified to Z. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Yes, it is like that. You have been asked that already at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668648/methods-to-do-outlier-detection-in-sound-recognition